# How to merge in smaller units in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, merge

I guess this is a easy question , but i could not find an answer .
I have created a branch A from default almost 6 months ago , I worked for 2 month in that branch and during that 2 months i periodically merged default into A .

Now after almost 4 months I have to merge my branch A with default.

Is there any way to merge in smaller units ? I want to do many small merges instead of one large merge !

Comment: I didn't understand his solution , Can anyone please give more explanation , I am not an expert in Mercurial .Let I am at branch A's head revision 400 and I want it to merge it with branch B whose Head revision is 402 . How to merge them incrementally ?

Comment: Which part doesn't make sense? jkerian is saying: update to `default`, then merge each revision from the `A` branch one at a time, resolving conflicts as you go. You can get a list of the revisions to merge from `hg log -r"ancestor(A, default)::A"`.